# Неправильно отображается текущая позиция ViewPager

Tags: android

```
viewPager.getCurrentItem()
```

не правильно работает с 0 и последний элементом фрагмента, Как быть?

Нахожусь я на 0 фрагменте, нажимаю кнопку, в логах результат что я якобы нахожусь на 0 фрагменте, хотя на самом деле я на 1 фрагменте

Comment: Вы же сами написали, что находитесь на 0 фрагменте, и в логи выводится 0. Что тут неправильно?

Comment: Нет я выше написал, что нахожусь на 0 фрагменте, нажал на кнопку, значит перешел на 1 фрагмент, а в логах показывает что я на 0 фрагменте, я на 2 в логах 1, я на 3 в логах 2, я на 4 в логах 3

Comment: А кто ж знает, что там за волшебную кнопку вы нажимаете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такое дело.

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int pos) {
                 int  currentPosition = pos; //правильный результат
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: Странно конечно но в логах и так и так число одинаковое. тобишь getCurrnet==currentPosition